# Does the ojAlgo matrix library supports multi-threading?

Tags: multithreading, ojalgo

I am working on a project that requires inversion of multiple large dense matrix. I would like to know if ojAlgo supports multi-threading.

I do notice the github page for ojAlgo is tagged with multi-threading, however I am unable to find any documentation about it.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, and that's stated in many different places. What documentation do you need? It just is multi-threaded (when possible and efficient). You don't need to do anything.

Comment: I see. thanks for the information !